# How to make an Android App as an SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I've got an Android app, which my client requests to package as an SDK.
The SDK should be called with something like SDK.open({parameters}), will open a new activity and will allow to close itself.

Needless to say that the SDK should be compiled and have only it's interface open for the public.

P.S - the project uses NDK as well, if has any influence.

I have no idea where to start - help would be appreciated :)

**EDIT**:
The real need is to take an existing activity, with all it's assets, 'res' folder, NDK code and more - and package into 'something' that can be incorporated into any other app and called upon need. When needed, it should be able to close itself and return to the original app that called it, releasing all it's memory.

Thanks

Comment: sdk stays for software development kit, code upon people create their own code, like you do with java. Probably you are looking for something different from an SDK.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a public intent which other apps can call? That sounds more like what you need.

Comment: Please talk to a client which knows what he's talking about, instead of a manager...

Comment: I think a public intent could be the answer. Though it should package inside an interface to the NDK as well, and internal files ('res' folder, assets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I've built apps off of the same library. You can run `Activitys` and anything you may need in the library, and hook it into a different app. For instance, if you look at [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rounded.ncc&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5yb3VuZGVkLm5jYyJd), and [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roundedco.cony&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5yb3VuZGVkY28uY29ueSJd), they look almost identical, but its because I used a single library for both. To create a new version of the app, I just need a single activity that starts the library. To customize the app, I have a class of statics in the app that I set from with the single page that initializes the app:

```
import com.mylibrarypackage.SplashScreen;
import com.mylibrarypackage.util.Constants;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class NCC extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Unique FacebookId
        Constants.facebookId = "xxx";

        //Unique Twitter Keys
        Constants.consumerKey = "xxx";
        Constants.consumerSecret = "xxx";

        //Flurry Key
        Constants.flurryKey ="xxx";

        //Font name
        Constants.fontName = "MuseoSans.ttf";
        Constants.boldfontName = "MuseoSans_500.ttf";



        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    }
}
```

Libraries are a really nice way to built generic apps.

Answer (score 1):

"SDK" stands for Software Development Kit. I pretty much doubt your customer really understands what he talks about as APP cannot be "packaged as SDK".

**EDIT:**

Anyone can send intent to your **exported** activity so it's mostly what you need. Set `exported="true"`, add some checks so your app won't crash when sent broken intent and you should be ready. Depending on your seeds you may want to handle being called with `startActivityForResults()`. But neither of these makes your app `SDK`.

Comment: The need is to take an activity and make it launchable in any app. The activity interacts with NDK, assets and 'res' files.

Comment: I guess he wants to include parts of his app as standalone, so that the user doesnt have to install both apps. Like the [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) library...

Answer (score 0):

Do it as a [library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

You will want to package it as a standalone .jar File. Like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html).
You can package the compiled code to a .jar, and have the resources in the library project. This is a good solution for both of you.

A .apk file actually is a .zip file, like a .jar file, so you could try to use the resources from a packaged .apk.